# 'AxesSubplot' object is not callable after reopen Tkinter window with plot

Tags: matplotlib, tkinter, canvas

I created a Graph `class`. The y-values of its `objects` are supposed to be updated at a later stage. The `plot` should be showed in a new window by clicking on a `Tkinter button`. So far, it works that the window with the `plot` is opened, when the `button` is clicked. But once I close the window with the `plot' and try to reopen the window, the following error is given:

TypeError: 'AxesSubplot' object is not callable

I use the following code:

```
import tkinter
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg)
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

root= tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry('800x800+50+50')
root.title('Spiel')

class Graph():
        
        def __init__(self, y):
            
            self.y = y
            
        def plot(self):
            self.window_graph = tkinter.Toplevel(root)
            self.window_graph.title("Graph")
            self.window_graph.geometry("300x300")
            
            self.fig = Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=55)
            self.plot = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
            self.plot.set_xlim([0,13])
            self.plot.set_ylim([0,400])
        
            #colors = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "black"]
        
            self.line, = self.plot.plot(range(0,7),self.y,'r-', marker="o")
        
            self.plot.set_xlabel("Runde")
            self.plot.set_ylabel("Punkte")
            #self.plot.legend()
            self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master = self.window_graph)  
            self.canvas.draw()
            self.canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=0)
 
            
y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] 
graph_plot = Graph(y)

def plotting():
    graph_plot.plot()

tkinter.Button(root, text="Graph", command=plotting).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Does anybody has a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue arises because you are setting `self.plot = self.fig.add_subplot(111)`. In Python, this overrides the function definition for that class:

```py
>>> def func():
...     pass
...
>>> func
<function func at 0x7f1f6d281f30>
>>> func = "abc"
>>> func
'abc'
```

Simply rename either your function or variable.